# Adding borders to image on click or mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-charts

I want to add round borders to selected image areas on a map, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You may use jQuery:

```
$('body').on('click', 'img', function() {
    $(this).addClass('with-round-corners');
});
```

Comment: I want to apply the border, which should be round, only on selected image areas <area> tags, how do I do it?

Comment: use webkit-border-radius:50% with this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS

```
img{
    border:none;
}
img:hover{
    border:1px solid;
}
```

Comment: I want to apply the border, which should be round, only on selected image areas <area> tags, I do not think this would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
img
{
border:0px;
}
img:hover
{
border:1px solid black;
border-radius:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below JQuery code on click :

```
$(imageAreasSelector).css({ 'border': '1px solid Red' });
$(imageAreasSelector).css({ 'border-radius': '5px' });
```

Comment: Would have done that, unfortunately the image selectors does not have any id. It is populated dynamically from server side(ASP.NET) which does not let you add any id attribute.